# What could i put in response in @ApiOperation of Swagger

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-2.0

In this code could i use Status.class @ApiOperation when this method return Response.noContent.build();?

```
    @DELETE
    @Path("/property/{id}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Delete", notes = "Delete a persisted property from data source.", response = Status.class??)
    public Response delete(String id){
    ...
    ...
    return Response.noContent().build();
    }
```

Comment: It is javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status

Comment: Since you're not returning a body, I don't think using `Status` would make any sense. Right now that endpoint will just return a `204 No Content`, which is fine.

Comment: that is true. I did not return body and i return 204 No Content.

Comment: this method returns 204 No Content but my question is waht could i put in return of @ApiOperation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit the `response` part and it will use `Void.class` by default. From the [docs](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/apidocs/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiOperation.html#response()):

> `public abstract Class<?> response`
>
> The response type of the operation.
>   In JAX-RS applications, **the return type of the method would automatically be used, unless it is `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`. In that case, the operation return type would default to `void` as the actual response type cannot be known.** (emphasis mine)
>
> Setting this property would override any automatically-derived data type.
>
> If the value used is a class representing a primitive (`Integer`, `Long`, ...) the corresponding primitive type will be used.
>
> **Default**:
>
> `java.lang.Void.class`